# Library of IBM Design charts

Tags: design, charts, library, design-frameworks

Does anybody know which library IBM uses to create the [charts](https://www.ibm.com/design/language/experience/data-visualization/interaction) in their design guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

They are definitely using [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) with some custom styling (open "Sources" tab in Chrome, design/assets/language/app.js clearly is a bundle with D3 v4.9.1 imported at the top).